# valueForKeyPath failing with nested NSMutableDictionary objects

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary, key-value-observing, keypaths

On my class I have two data objects: 'dataDict' (property) and 'prevDict' (instance variable) which are both `NSMutableDictionary` objects.  In these multi-level dictionaries all the 'nodes' are themselves `NSMutableDictionary` objects and all the 'leaves' are NSString values.

Most of the time, these dictionaries will compare to be the same.  But, when the new incoming data is different, I want to capture those changes via KVO and then save the new incoming dictionary.  The recursive calls are the thing that fires off all the KVO changes.

Below is the code for recursively determining if the new incoming data (in property 'dataDict') is different than what's in the 'prevDictionary'.  The initial call is:

```
[self postChangesFromPrevDict:prevDict usingKeyPath:@"dataDict"];
prevDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.dataDict copyItems:YES];
```

If there's a change on a given leaf, it should update that in the dictionary and produce a KVO notification.

A sample 'newPath' string value could be "dataDict.group.name.points" -- in which the 'key' value is "points".

In the debugger breakpoint noted, I can see the values of 'curStr' and 'newStr' as, say, "120" and "121" with the these two values being correctly obtained from `prevDict` and `dataDict`, respectively.

**If I obtain a value from a given keyPath then set it again using that SAME key path, why am I getting an `NSUnknownKeyException`?**

I do know that all my dictionaries involved are mutable.

```
-(void) postChangesFromPrevDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)prevDictionary
               usingKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    NSArray *keys = [prevDictionary allKeys];
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
        id obj = [prevDictionary objectForKey:key];
        NSString *newPath = [keyPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@",key]];
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
            [self postChangesFromPrevDict:obj usingKeyPath:newPath];
        else {
            NSString *curStr = obj;
            NSString *newStr = [self valueForKeyPath:newPath];
            //debug breakpoint
            if (![newStr isEqualToString:curStr]) {
                @try {
                    [self setValue:newStr forKeyPath:newPath];
                }
                @catch (NSException *__unused exception) {
                    NSLog(@"Can't set key on %@",newPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: To recurse, I test for an `NSDictionary` class which is fine as `NSMutableDictionary` is a subclass thereof.

Comment: What's the full error of your `NSUnknownKeyException`? Could you print the exception rather than just the path if needed? Could it be that underneath a NSMutableDictionary, there is a NSDictionary at some sublevel, or in other world a non-mutable?

Comment: `curStr` is the string in `prevDictionary`, `newStr` is the string in `self`, if `curStr` != `newStr` then you set the string in `self` to `newStr` again. Why?

Comment: Is `prevDict` supposed to be a deep copy?